# How can i skip an iteration in for loop in dictionary without getting an error, that dict changed size

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop

Alright, so I need to delete a node and all incident edges from the graph.
But when node == key, and I delete it, I get a Runtime Error, that dictionary changed size
How can I deal with this?

```
def del_node(graph, node):
    """
    (dict, int) -> (dict)

    Delete a node and all incident edges from the graph.

    >>> del_node({1: [2, 5], 2: [1, 4], 3: [4], 4: [2, 3], 5: [1, 4]}, 4)
    {1: [2, 5], 2: [1], 3: [], 5: [1]}
    """
    for key in graph:
        if key == node:
            del graph[key]
            continue
        for item in graph[key]:
            if item == node:
                graph[key].remove(item)
    return graph
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .copy() on the for key in the graph so that you create a copy of the dict for iteration and still dynamically manipulate the graph.

As such:

```
for key in graph.copy():
```

Now, since you are creating a copy of the dict, this sure will cause a Space and Time Complexity of O(n).

Another option is to create a list of all the keys on the fly and then iterating through them as such:

```
for key in list(graph):
```

This will persist the keys in a list and will allow updating the dict parallelly.
Although, this will not be any different on the Space and Time complexities.